# Use python to automate series of file comparison functions against directory of files

Tags: python, function, automation

The functions below must be run in order to output cosine similarity in degrees and radians between two files. I want to automate this to process 500 files in same directory against the first file (one file at a time against first file): RUMO4009_M.txt. I would like the keep the output for all processed files to see output for each of the 500 files compared with first file. Example Output:

> File RUMO4009_M.txt : 2836 lines,  509 words,  278 distinct words File
> RUMO5038_M.txt : 2672 lines,  479 words,  212 distinct words The
> cosine between the documents is  0.768315. The angle between the
> documents is  0.694592 radians or  40 degrees.

```
import math
import string
import sys

##################################
### Read a text file ###
##################################
def read_file(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            data = f.read()
        return data
    except IOError:
        print("Error opening or reading input file: ", filename)
        sys.exit()

# using a global variable to map upper case to lower case which will help functions speed up further down.
translation_table = str.maketrans(string.punctuation+string.ascii_uppercase," "*len(string.punctuation)+string.ascii_lowercase)
        
#################################################
### Split the text lines into words ###
#################################################
def get_words_from_line_list(text):
    text = text.translate(translation_table)
    word_list = text.split()
    return word_list
get_words_from_line_list(read_file('RUMO4009_M.txt'))

#################################################
### Split the text lines into words ###
#################################################
def get_words_from_line_list(text):
    text = text.translate(translation_table)
    word_list = text.split()
    return word_list
get_words_from_line_list(read_file('RUMO5038_M.txt'))


#################################################
### Define dotProduct and vector_angle ###
#################################################

def dotProduct(P1, P2):
    tot=0.0

    for key in P1:

        if key in P2:
            tot+=(P1[key]*P2[key])

    return tot

# angle in radians between document vectors
def vector_angle(P1, P2): 
    num=dotProduct(P1, P2)
    den=math.sqrt(dotProduct(P1, P1)*dotProduct(P2, P2))

    return math.acos(num/den)



##############################################
### Count frequency of each word ###
##############################################
def count_frequency(word_list):
    D = {}
    for new_word in word_list:
        if new_word in D:
            D[new_word] = D[new_word] + 1
        else:
            D[new_word] = 1
    return D

count_frequency(get_words_from_line_list(read_file('RUMO4009_M.txt')))

##############################################
### Count frequency of each word ###
##############################################
def count_frequency(word_list):
    D = {}
    for new_word in word_list:
        if new_word in D:
            D[new_word] = D[new_word] + 1
        else:
            D[new_word] = 1
    return D

count_frequency(get_words_from_line_list(read_file('RUMO5038_M.txt')))


###### Define Word Frequencies #########

def word_frequencies_for_file(filename,verbose=False):

    line_list = read_file(filename)
    word_list = get_words_from_line_list(line_list) 
    freq_mapping = count_frequency(word_list)

    print("File", filename, ":", ) 
    print(len(line_list), "lines, ", ) 
    print(len(word_list), "words, ", ) 
    print(len(freq_mapping), "distinct words")
    return freq_mapping 

word_frequencies_for_file('RUMO4009_M.txt')


def word_frequencies_for_file(filename,verbose=False):

    line_list = read_file(filename)
    word_list = get_words_from_line_list(line_list) 
    freq_mapping = count_frequency(word_list)

    print("File", filename, ":", ) 
    print(len(line_list), "lines, ", ) 
    print(len(word_list), "words, ", ) 
    print(len(freq_mapping), "distinct words")
    return freq_mapping 

word_frequencies_for_file('RUMO5038_M.txt')


##### Cosine Similarity function #######

def document_similarity(filename_1, filename_2, verbose=True):
    """DOCSTRING"""
    '''document_similarity function compares two docs for similarities in line, word, and distinct words count.
    The line: sorted_word_list_1 = word_frequencies_for_file(filename_1, verbose) is biggest
    issue with efficiency.'''
    sorted_word_list_1 = word_frequencies_for_file(filename_1, verbose)
    sorted_word_list_2 = word_frequencies_for_file(filename_2, verbose)
    cosine = vector_angle(sorted_word_list_1,sorted_word_list_2)
    # Use f-strings; see https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/ for more information
    if verbose:
        print(f"The cosine between the documents is {cosine : 0.6f}.")
        print(f"The angle between the documents is {math.acos(cosine) : 0.6f} radians or {math.acos(cosine)*180/math.pi : .0f} degrees.")


document_similarity('RUMO4009_M.txt','RUMO5038_M.txt')
```

OUTPUT:

File RUMO4009_M.txt :
2836 lines,
509 words,
278 distinct words
File RUMO5038_M.txt :
2672 lines,
479 words,
212 distinct words
File RUMO4009_M.txt :
2836 lines,
509 words,
278 distinct words
File RUMO5038_M.txt :
2672 lines,
479 words,
212 distinct words
The cosine between the documents is  0.768315.
The angle between the documents is  0.694592 radians or  40 degrees.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  
"Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow.
You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a *specific* question about your implementation.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials and documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
### COSINE SIMILARITY
### USE THIS BELOW TO LOOP THROUGH DIRECTORY OF TXT DOCUMENTS 
### COMPARED TO SINGLE SPECIFIED TXT FILE

### %%writefile example.txt

# Import libraries
import math
import string
import sys
import glob

# Locate filenames
filenames = glob.glob('*.txt')
print(filenames)

# Using a global variable to map upper case to lower case which will help functions speed up further down.
translation_table = str.maketrans(string.punctuation+string.ascii_uppercase," "*len(string.punctuation)+string.ascii_lowercase)

##################################
### Read a text file ###
##################################

def read_file(filename):
    try:
        with open(filename, 'r') as f:
            data = f.read()
        return data
    except IOError:
        print("Error opening or reading input file: ", filename)
        sys.exit()
        

#################################################
### Split the text lines into words ###
#################################################

def get_words_from_line_list(text):
    text = text.translate(translation_table)
    word_list = text.split()
    return word_list


#################################################
### Define dotProduct and vector_angle ###
#################################################

# dotProduct
def dotProduct(P1, P2):
    tot=0.0

    for key in P1:

        if key in P2:
            tot+=(P1[key]*P2[key])

    return tot

# angle in radians between document vectors
def vector_angle(P1, P2): 
    num=dotProduct(P1, P2)
    den=math.sqrt(dotProduct(P1, P1)*dotProduct(P2, P2))

    return math.acos(num/den)


##############################################
### Count frequency of each word ###
##############################################

def count_frequency(word_list):
    D = {}
    for new_word in word_list:
        if new_word in D:
            D[new_word] = D[new_word] + 1
        else:
            D[new_word] = 1
    return D


##############################################
### Define Word Frequencies ###
##############################################

def word_frequencies_for_file(filename,verbose=False):

    line_list = read_file(filename)
    word_list = get_words_from_line_list(line_list) 
    freq_mapping = count_frequency(word_list)

    print("File", filename, ":", ) 
    print(len(line_list), "lines, ", ) 
    print(len(word_list), "words, ", ) 
    print(len(freq_mapping), "distinct words")
    return freq_mapping 


##############################################
### Cosine Similarity function  ###
##############################################

def document_similarity(filename_1, filename_2, verbose=True):
    """DOCSTRING"""
    '''document_similarity function compares two docs for similarities in line, word, and distinct words count.
    The line: sorted_word_list_1 = word_frequencies_for_file(filename_1, verbose) is biggest
    issue with efficiency.'''
    sorted_word_list_1 = word_frequencies_for_file(filename_1, verbose)
    sorted_word_list_2 = word_frequencies_for_file(filename_2, verbose)
    angle = vector_angle(sorted_word_list_1,sorted_word_list_2)
    # Use f-strings; see https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/ for more information
    if verbose:
        print(f"The cosine between the documents is {math.cos(angle) : 0.6f}.")
        print(f"The angle between the documents is {angle : 0.6f} radians or {angle*180/math.pi : .0f} degrees.")
    return math.cos(angle)
        

# create empty list
cosine_array=[]

# LOOP THROUGH DIRECTORY OF TXT DOCUMENTS
# s represents all target TXT files to compare against source (main) TXT 1 i.e.: 'RUMO4009.M.txt')
for s in filenames:
    get_words_from_line_list(read_file('RUMO4009_M.txt')) #Change TXT 1 here to compare all files against
    get_words_from_line_list(read_file(s))
    count_frequency(get_words_from_line_list(read_file('RUMO4009_M.txt'))) #Change TXT 1 to compare all files against
    count_frequency(get_words_from_line_list(read_file(s)))
    new_cosine = document_similarity('RUMO4009_M.txt',s) #Change TXT 1 to compare all files against; keep s variable
    cosine_array.append((new_cosine,s))

### NOW SORT RESULTS IN COSINE DESCENDING ORDER ### 
# Most similar target txt files (to source file) will be listed first
# 1.0 value is highest value of similarity; if your source txt is in the target directory,
# it will be compared with itself and have the highest similarity possible: a cosine of 1.0.
# 0.0 value would be the lowest cosine value of similarity

cosine_array.sort(reverse=True,key=lambda x: x[0])

### NOW PRINT OUT SORTED RESULTS ### 

cosine_array


### NOW PLACE SORTED RESULTS INTO A PANDAS DATAFRAME AND EXPORT TO CSV FILE ###

import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(cosine_array)
df=df.rename(columns={0:'Cosine between Source and Target TXT',1:'Target TXT'})
df.to_csv("results.csv",index=False)
df
```

Comment: Series of functions above can be used to compare directory of txt docs for similarity using Cosine Similarity approach.